# using a list of months ask user fo sales for each month and append a list for sales

Tags: python, function

I have a list with the months of the year,
i have a second list that is empty called sales

how would i go about asking a user to enter the slate for each month.
ie.

```
Jan>>>user enters sales 
Feb>>>user enters sales
```

etc.
the amounts that the user enters should be added to the sales list.

im new to python

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to take user input? Or are you asking how to append elements to a list? Both of these are trivially solvable with 5 minutes spent on google. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"] # and so on
sales = []
for month in months:
    sales.append(input("Enter sales for %s" % month))
```

I recommend checking out a simple tutorial on python programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the months lists through a for loop and prompt the user for input. for example take a look at the following code.

```
months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'aprl']
sales = []

for idx, month in enumerate(months):
    sales.append(int(input('enter sale')))

print(sales)
```

Comment: Why use `enumerate` if you're not going to use `idx`?

Comment: in the above example enumerate need not be used. I was trying something else out and unknowingly added the code

Comment: Thanks All very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
months = ["January", "Febuary", "March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
sales = []

for month in months:
    sales.append(input(month+"> "))

for i in range(0, len(months)):
    print(months[i] + " Sales " + sales[i])
```